# How to update movie without exporting

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation

I've already asked a similar question some time ago but now I can be much more specific. Is it possible to update a movie file's metadata without having to rewrite it? I mean, Quicktime/QTKit had an `updateMovieFile` method to do this, I can't believe AVFoundation doesn't have something similar.

Currently I have to copy the movie with `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` but it's slow and inconvenient (I'm just changing metadata!!), especially when performing a batch process.

How does iTunes update a movie's database when you edit movie info?. I'm sure it uses AVFoundation but it doesn't rewrite the movie file as far as I know.

I would appreciate any guidance.

FYI, using the old Quicktime method seems to no longer work. Movie metadata is not changed when added to iTunes. I don't know why but I suppose this is due to iTunes moving from Quicktime to AVFoundation.

Thanks in advance.

Ricardo

Comment: “I don't know why but I suppose is due to iTunes moved from Quicktime to AVFoundation.” Why would that matter? If you've added the metadata to the file, iTunes should pick it up no matter how you did it. Does the metadata show up when you Get Info on the file in the Finder?

Comment: I don't know why but the fact is if I change iTunes artwork metadata that way, it is shown in Finder but it doesn't appear when added to iTunes. Anyway I'd prefer to do the trick using AVFoundation since I'm using ARC (64 bits land).